# Emacs M-x query-replace wrap around the document?

Tags: emacs

I use `M-x query-replace` on Emacs (`M-%`) quite often, and I like that I have the flexibility to choose between these options:

```
Spacebar               Replace text and find the next occurrence
Del                    Leave text as is and find the next occurrence
. (period)             Replace text, then stop looking for occurrences
! (exclamation point)  Replace all occurrences without asking
^ (caret)              Return the cursor to previously replaced text
```

Is there a way to:

- Cycle back to the beginning of the document after we hit the end of the document?
- Reverse the direction of the search-and-replace in the middle of the execution of the command.

Comment: `query-replace-string` (and its regexp sibling) only go forward, you'd have to rewrite a big chunk of code to go backward. There's no option to wrap (there might be a package out there somewhere), but that's easy to work around: `M-<` (`beginning-of-buffer`), do the replacement, `C-2 C-SPC` (go back to the next-to-last mark set (by `M-<`)).

Comment: Interesting idea. Could be quite convenient. [Ask the emacs gurus](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel). They may like it enough, so they implement it.

Comment: Probably you should change your post so not to make everyone confused: that's `query-replace` (As for your question, can't help you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`query-replace` is a very important function, so I'm reluctant to change it globally. What I've done instead is to copy this to a new function, `my-query-replace`, which initially has the same behaviour. Then I advise this function to repeat the query-replace search at the beginning of the buffer once it reaches the end. This might be overly cautious - you could modify the advice to apply to `query-replace` instead of `my-query-replace`, and enable this behaviour globally.

```lisp
;; copy the original query-replace-function 
(fset 'my-query-replace 'query-replace)

;; advise the new version to repeat the search after it 
;; finishes at the bottom of the buffer the first time:    
(defadvice my-query-replace 
  (around replace-wrap 
          (FROM-STRING TO-STRING &optional DELIMITED START END))
  "Execute a query-replace, wrapping to the top of the buffer 
   after you reach the bottom"
  (save-excursion
    (let ((start (point)))
      ad-do-it
      (beginning-of-buffer)
      (ad-set-args 4 (list (point-min) start))
      ad-do-it)))

;; Turn on the advice    
(ad-activate 'my-query-replace)
```

Once you have evaluated this code, you can call the wrapped search with `M-x my-query-replace`, or bind it to something convenient for you:

```lisp
(global-set-key "\C-cq" 'my-query-replace)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've using below for work with Emacs 24+:

```
;; query replace all from buffer start
(fset 'my-query-replace-all 'query-replace)
(advice-add 'my-query-replace-all
            :around
            #'(lambda(oldfun &rest args)
               "Query replace the whole buffer."
               ;; set start pos
               (unless (nth 3 args)
                 (setf (nth 3 args)
                       (if (use-region-p)
                           (region-beginning)
                         (point-min))))
               (unless (nth 4 args)
                 (setf (nth 4 args)
                       (if (use-region-p)
                           (region-end)
                         (point-max))))
               (apply oldfun args)))
(global-set-key "\C-cr" 'my-query-replace-all)
```

Regard the region replace case, and any START and END args passed.